# Chrome not using defs of an external svg file

Tags: google-chrome, svg, mozilla

In my `page.html` I have a `svg` element calling another svg file:

```
<!doctype html><body bgcolor="#666">
<svg><use xlink:href="drawings.svg#draw1"/></svg>
```

And this is the `drawings.svg` file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3)" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgba(200,200,200,0.3)" />
    </linearGradient>
    <symbol id="draw1">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%" fill="white" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="15%" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
    </symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

This works perfectly in Firefox 56.0.1:

[image: correct in Firefox]

On the other hand Chrome 61 is not applying the gradient; it just shows the white circle:

[image: incorrect in Chrome]

Is there another way to refer to the gradients I defined in drawings.svg?

Comment: I'm on chrome 61. I just tried it, it looks like there's a grey gradient. https://jsfiddle.net/duonyzy6/

Comment: The problem is when the SVG defs are in another file

Comment: dude did you find the solution?